# Ionic 3 / Angular 5 http.post request header not getting passed

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to hit an API to do a pretty simple `get` request but the options doesn't seem to be getting supplied as I'm getting an authentication error, even though the same auth token works on Postman. Here's the code:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';



@Injectable()
export class UsersService {

  private nearby_url: string = APP_CONFIG.apiEndpoint + '/users/closest/';
  private me_url: string = APP_CONFIG.apiEndpoint + '/users/me/';
  private conversations_url: string = APP_CONFIG.apiEndpoint + '/users/conversations/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  createAuthorizationHeader() {
    var headers = new HttpHeaders();
    // get auth token

    // append auth token to headers
    headers.append("Authorization", 'Token xxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyyyzzzzzzzzz');

    return headers
  }

  getPersonResponse(url): Observable<PersonResponse> {
    const options = {
      headers: this.createAuthorizationHeader()
    };

    return this.http.get(url, options)
      .map((response: Response) => response)
      .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.error || 'Server error'));
  }

  getNearby(): Observable<PersonResponse> {
    return this.getPersonResponse(this.nearby_url);
  }

  getMe(): Observable<PersonResponse> {
    return this.getPersonResponse(this.me_url);
  }

  getConversations(): Observable<PersonResponse> {
    return this.getPersonResponse(this.conversations_url);
  }

}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change to something like

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders()
            .set("X-CustomHeader", "custom header value");
```

> Notice that we are building the HTTPHeaders object by chaining
>   successive set() methods. This is because HTTPHeaders is immutable,
>   and its API methods do not cause object mutation. Instead, a call to
>   set will return a new HTTPHeaders object containing the new value
>   properties.

More on the same - https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/services

Comment: Lifesaver, thank you!

Comment: append works too.

Comment: append used to work for old Headers after the introduction of HttpClient we cannot use append @manishkumar

Comment: ill try it . Thanks for updating.